# Cant change text of UITextView and UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have a viewcontroller with a textview and a label and i want to change the text on both of them before i load the view.

```
- (IBAction)loadCardInformation:(id)sender{
ciViewController = [[CardInformationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CardInformationViewController" bundle:nil];
[ciViewController.infoLabel setText:@"ROFL"];
[ciViewController.infoText setText:@"CAKE"];
[self.view addSubview:(UIView *)ciViewController.view];
```

}

I have hooked both the label and the textview to outlets, but nothing is changing.

Comment: When you call `setText` methods, is the UILabel not `nil` ? I had encountered problems that after calling `-initWithNibName:bundle:`, but the IBLayouts didn't be assigned valid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set these in `viewDidLoad` of the viewController. At the point where you are currently setting the properties they have not been loaded.

Also

```
[self.view addSubview:(UIView *)ciViewController.view];
```

this looks like something you should most likely not be doing.

Comment: You need to look at the flow off your app. There are two main way to investigate using a `UINavigationController` to create a stack or presenting your `viewContollers` modally. Those are the common ways. Chances are one of those two will be fine if not you may need to dig a little deeper